# La paginación de laravel parece omitir la condición de búsqueda al pasar página

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, paginación

En una de las vistas en la que estoy trabajando, tengo que recibir un dato desde una búsqueda y según las coincidencias con la BD, mostrar el listado correspondiente.

```
public function searchCatchProduct(Request $request){

        $description = $request->input('description');

        $productSearchFind =Product::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$description.'%')
                ->paginate(5);

//        dd($productSearchFind);
        if (!empty($productSearchFind[0])) {

            return view('product.productSearchCatch',compact('productSearchFind'));
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('product.productSearch')
                            ->with(['message' => 'PRODUCTO ' . $description . ' NO ENCONTRADO']);
        }
    } //fin searchCatchProduct
```

La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('/product/productSearchCatch', 'ProductController@searchCatchProduct')->name('product.productSearchCatch');
```

La vista utiliza un foreach, que a priori hace lo que le pides sin problema.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @include('includes.sidebar')
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @include('includes.message')
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style=" color: #386fa6;font-weight: bold; text-align: center !important">Listado de Productos Encontrados</div>
                <table class="table-hover table-sm">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>descripción</th>
                        <th>Financiación</th>
                        <th>Duración</th>
                        <th>Centro</th>
                        <th>Comentarios</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($productSearchFind as $prod)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$prod->cod}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->description}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->funding}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->lapse}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->center}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->comments}}</td>
                        <td>{{$prod->stock}}</td>

                        <td><a href="{{ route('product.ProductUpdate', $prod->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Actualizar</a></td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('delete-{{$prod->id}}').submit()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</a>
                            <form id="delete-{{$prod->id}}" action="{{route('product.destroy',$prod->id)}}" method="POST">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="{{route('product.searchAssignment', $prod->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Préstamo</a></td>
                    <tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- Paginate -->
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center pt-2">
                    {{$productSearchFind->links()}}
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Como se puede observar (disculpar la imagen y la broma para la prueba..) funciona correctamente.
[image: Detalle de paginate correcto]

Pero en cuanto avanzas de página, evita el where de la consulta, añade más páginas y muestra toda la tabla...

[image: Detalle error paginate]

En qué falla?...llevo horas haciendo cambios y revisiones, sin saber el porqué..Gracias.

Comment: He probado por otra pregunta similar con append.. {{$productSearchFind->appends(['productSearchFind' => $productSearchFind])->links()}} pero sigue dando error

Comment: Hola que tal, por lo que veo tienes una ruta tipo GET con request es decir pasas una variable recien cargada la URL, que me imagino queda algo asi URL_del_proyecto?description=Lo_que_se_busca.

Si ese es el caso al momento de paginar pierde la referencia de la variable description si te das cuenta debio haber cambiado la URL a URL_del_proyecto?page=2 pero la varibale desciption no se envia, la paginacion funciona bien lo que no esta funcionando es el filtrado, confirmame si es eso para buscarle una solucion

Comment: Gracias por contestar, porque llevo dias buscando cuando tengo un rato alguna solución a este asunto..

Comment: La búsqueda que da problemas, en principio, parece recoger bien los datos: http://localhost/ORTOPREST/Ortoprest/public/product/productSearchCatch?_token=TPsW1kSdgbnSgau5CTltYcxqltxaB1lXl0mdEEH5&description=baston

Comment: Pero al pasar la página aunque parece recoger correctamente los 6 productos que tengo para esa muestra, y que deben ser dos páginas, algo sale mal. Esta es la url: (http://localhost/ORTOPREST/Ortoprest/public/product/productSearchCatch?productSearchFind[total]=6&productSearchFind[lastPage]=2&productSearchFind[perPage]=5&productSearchFind[currentPage]=1&productSearchFind[path]=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FORTOPREST%2FOrtoprest%2Fpublic%2Fproduct%2FproductSearchCatch&productSearchFind[pageName]=page&page=2)    algo hace ese filtrado, para que luego tire el resto de productos y paginación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo intenta hacer esto

Cambia

```
{{$productSearchFind->links()}}
```

Por

```
{!! $productSearchFind->appends(["description" => $description]) !!}
```

Con esto logras enviar la paginación con una variable extra

De igual forma tienes que enviar la variable **description** desde el controlador a la vista

En vez de:

```
return view('product.productSearchCatch',compact('productSearchFind'));
```

Yo lo utilizo asi:

```
return view('product.productSearchCatch',["description" => $description,"productSearchFind" => $productSearchFind]);
```

Espero te resulva el problema si no me dejas un comentario. Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!... La de pruebas que he hecho y webs que habré visitado buscando respuestas, y no se me había pasado por la mente la idea de añadir la variable de control.Caso cerrado!!!